# Regex: How would I get everything after a string?

Tags: regex

**(Solved - It's currently not possible with Javascript Regex to exclude part of a selected string as of this posting date)**

Searched around and couldn't find a clear example for this case.

Currently I have this text block:

```
Characteristics
Content: 100% Polyurethane
Backing: Polyester
Weight: 20 oz/ly (620 gr/lm)
Width: 54" (137cm)
Bolt Size: 35 yards (32 m)
Maintenance: W/B-Clean w
```

I'd like to extract any text after `Content:` (note the space)

So that it extracts `100% Polyurethane`

Currently I have this - (But it includes `Content:`):
http://regexr.com/3dbct

My purpose is to have a regex command that can later extract anything after `Width:`, `Backing:`, etc.

**Edit: Requirement is we can't use any javascript, only regex**

Comment: `m = inp.match(/Content:\s*(.*)/); console.log(m[1])` - ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: I can't use any javascript to get `100% Polyurethane` -- not sure if it's possible to do this without javascript help

Comment: I can always replace the `Content: `, `Weight: `, etc after -- it's not really a huge deal, but I'm curious if it's possible without any outside help. (For my own curiosity)

Comment: Should just a simple `/.+?:(.*)/` work?

Comment: if you mean that you can ONLY use `.match` and not methods like `indexOf` and the like, then what you currently have should work https://regex101.com/r/zO2uE8/1

Comment: If you use this in: http://regexr.com/3dbct it won't work.

Comment: To clarify my comment, here is a demo: http://regexr.com/3dbd3

Comment: But doesn't that already give you what you want? Can't you use $1 to get 100% Polyurethane?

Comment: @StephenCollins that won't work unfortunately, also I need it to be flexible so later I can specify `Width: `, `Weight: ` etc.

Comment: Then I am not understanding. Using an expression like /.+:\s(.*)/ gives me access to each value. https://regex101.com/r/rV1xI5/2

Comment: I need to be specific because what happens when a text block doesn't contain `Backing: `? Then the array will be out of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:Content|Backing|Width):\s*(.*$)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/bR1oU4/1).

There's no way to exclude the bit before the `:` because of JavaScript regex limitations but you could just capture the content matched in capturing group 1.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for -- it's not possible with Javascript Regex to exclude `Content: ` without post processing.

Comment: @sojim2 These limitations are because the JS regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds or discarding options like `\K`. It's possible that these may be available in the future (ES7).

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, you just need to grab the value of the capture group (what you have in parentheses).

Note: the `m` flag in the regex means:

> multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string)

Also, the `exec` method returns an array (or `null` if there is no match). The first item in the array, index 0, is the full match, and each index after that is each capture group, in order. So, index 1 is the first capture group, which is what you want in this case.

Update: I made it more generic. Now it loops through an array of data labels, and grabs the text after each of them.

```js
var dataLabels = ['Content','Backing','Weight','Width','Bolt Size','Maintenance'];

var input = 'Characteristics\nContent: 100% Polyurethane\nBacking: Polyester\nWeight: 20 oz/ly (620 gr/lm)\nWidth: 54" (137cm)\nBolt Size: 35 yards (32 m)\nMaintenance: W/B-Clean w';

var regex, i, match;

for(i = 0; i < dataLabels.length; i++) {
    regex = new RegExp(dataLabels[i] + ': (.*)', 'm');

    match = regex.exec(input);

    if(match !== null) {
        // do something with this
        console.log(dataLabels[i] + ' = ' + match[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have labeled Javascript, I really just need to be specific (I'm using webscraper.io) and it can only take 1 regex line to extract content, and I'd like not to have `Content: ` in the csv output

Comment: Yeah, you need to make it clear what you are doing from the beginning.